# UIPickerView reloadAllComponents not working, why?

Tags: ios7, delegates, xcode5, datasource, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView named UnitType, that displays its content based on what label I currently have selected (each label has a gesture recognizer associated with it) and so whenever a new label is selected I the recognizer is called in @implementation and in this method I say [UnitType reloadAllComponents]. at this point I have a few questions:

does this command call my delegate and data source methods? if so, why does it not stop at my breakpoints that are in these methods.

either way that command should reload my picker with the correct content, it was working fine until recently but now, the labels in the picker are not reloading however, the number of objects is refreshing, so my picker shows more objects than actually exist. What could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Also I am new to iOS dev. so if something isn't clear please say so.